# How to uninstall Call of Duty Black Ops?

Tags: wine, games

Today, I installed Call of Duty Black Ops using Wine, but it wouldn't run. When I tried to uninstall it, however, I just kept running into problems.

For example, the installed application is not showing on wine installed application list.

I installed from a CD (Pirated Copy), which did not provide and uninstaller. Is there anything I can do to get rid of it?

I'm running kubuntu 16.10.

[image: No Uninstaller file]

Comment: You can just delete the wine prefix that you installed it into

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Installed it from a CD.

Answer (score 0):

I would just burn your entire Wine config to the ground. It's easy and about as effective as you can make it. Note that this will delete any Wine apps you have installed, and any files you have stored in your Wine prefix.

From a terminal, just run:

```
rm ~/.wine
```

If deleting your wineprefix isn't an option, you *could* just delete the folder from `~/.wine/drive_c/Games`, but there's no guarantee that this actually cleans up all of the files left behind by the "installer."

To get rid of any excess shortcuts, navigate to `~/.local/share/applications` and delete anything that looks like it doesn't belong.

Also, just to be on the safe side, I'd run an antivirus check using `clamav` or similar on your entire drive, just to be sure you weren't infected. Linux *can* get viruses, still.